# less showing ^M instead of going to a new line

Tags: less

I have a log file where `borg --progress` adds many lines separated by `^M`.

Weirdly, `less` puts the `^M` in the screen "as it is", instead of producing a new line.

Is there a reason for that?

How can I have `less` going to a new line when a `^M` sequence is found?

Comment: Does `xxd logfile` show this as `0d` byte? or maybe as literal `^M` (`5e4d`)?

Comment: `xxd` shows it as `0d`.